# Update a single object from a list using stream

Tags: java, java-8

I have a list of objects.  I need to update a single object from the list that match my filter.  I can do something like below:

```
List<MyObject> list = list.stream().map(d -> {
    if (d.id == 1) {
        d.name = "Yahoo";
        return d;
    }
    return d;
});
```

But my worry is i am like iterating through the whole list which may be up to 20k records.  I can do a `for loop` then `break`, but that one I think also will be slow.

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything. There's no terminal operation.

Comment: A simple rule, don't use streams while mutating objects. If a for loop with a `break` would be slow enough to find the first element of your preference, I doubt you should change the data structure you're using.

Comment: Unless you omitted important details in your question, the answer is: Use a `for` loop with `break`. There is nothing that can be any faster for a list with no order.
If your data structure is large and finding an element an important use-case, use a different data structure that can find things faster, such as a tree or hash set.

Answer (score 13):

Use `findFirst` so after finding the first matching element in the list remaining elements will not be processed

```
Optional<MyObject> result = list.stream()
                                .filter(obj->obj.getId()==1)
                                .peek(o->o.setName("Yahoo"))
                                .findFirst();
```

Or

```
  //will not return anything but will update the first matching object name

                              list.stream()
                              .filter(obj->obj.getId()==1)
                              .findFirst()
                              .ifPresent(o->o.setName("Yahoo"));
```

Comment: `map()` expects a return value. Use `peek()`, or better yet, `findFirst().ifPresent(o -> o.setName("Yahoo"))`.

Comment: Given the input is a `List`, there can be multiple entries that might be getting updated in OP's code. While here it's just a single element.

Comment: My understanding on this statement is `I need to update a single object from the list that match my filter` to update the first matching object in the list and break it @Naman

Comment: Well ya, I got it with a mix of what the title of the question meant. But another point would be *I can do a for loop then break, but that one I think also will be slow.*. Do you think `findFirst` would be efficient either? (@shmosel opinion on that?)

Comment: i'm not that good to figure which one gives better performance, but i just showed the way to do it by using streams @Naman

Comment: I wouldn't expect a stream to be faster than a simple for loop, unless you made it parallel.

Comment: does the streams internally use `for loop` ? @shmosel

Comment: Definitely some kind of loop.

Comment: `findFirst()` is a *short-circuiting* operation, which means, it fulfills the requirement to stop traversal once an element has been found. Still, it’s preferable to use `findAny()` when there should be only one occurrence, to document that there is no ordering constraint (which may improve the performance of parallel streams).

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Map instead of a list and save the id as a key.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Then you can extract it with `O(1)`.

Comment: Comparatively a better suggestion if performance is the impact.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how often you need to perform this logic on your input data.

If it happens to be several times, consider using a `Map` as suggested by **Raz**.
You can also transform your `List` into a `Map` using a `Stream`:

```java
Map<Integer, MyObject> map = list.stream()
                                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                     MyObject::getId
                                     Function.identity()
                                 ));
```

The first argument of `toMap` maps a stream item to the corresponding key in the map (here the ID of `MyObject`), and the second argument maps an item to the map value (here the `MyObject` item itself).

Constructing the map will cost you some time and memory, but once you have it, searching an item by ID is extremely fast.
The more often you search an item, the more constructing the map first pays off.

However, if you only ever need to update a single item and then forget about the whole list, just search for the right element, update it and you're done.

If your data is already sorted by ID, you can use binary search to find your item faster.

Otherwise, you need to iterate through your list until you find your item. In terms of performance, nothing will beat a simple loop here. But using `Stream` and `Optional` as shown in **Deadpool**'s answer is fine as well, and might result in clearer code, which is more important in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
.stream().peek(t->t.setTag(t.getTag().replace("/","")));
```

Do anything you want with the `peek()` method. Just keep in mind and be aware that according to the documentation the `peek()` method was intended to be used mainly for debugging and not in production, it is a lazy method. If, for example, you are not careful and put `findFirst()` before `peek()` then `peek()` it will not be called.